# Is Google Drive limiting my audio reproductions using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have developed a hybrid app where audios can be listened. In order not to make it heavy, **I have uploaded** those **audios to Google Drive and I have created references to them using HTML / JS**:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=12345audioId54321
```

However, **users are experiencing that some audios stop playing** randomly. I have noticed that too, although I am not able to reproduce it, following any specific steps.
**Do you know if Google Drive limits the use of the files** for some reason? I have not been able to find any official information about it.

If so, do you know if this **is something that can be fixed?**
Or... In the worst case scenario, **if this cannot be fixed, do you know of an alternative to Google Drive?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://support.google.com/drive/thread/14053003?hl=en

Comment: It is still a comment on a forum, not an official Google message. Thanks for sharing, though.
What about alternatives...? Dropbox? OneDrive? Will those ones work?

Comment: I really do not know but I suppose that anything on a free tier will have some limits. Perhaps you can try https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html and I am pretty sure that Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage will not suffer the issue.